# Evitar la division entre 0, validando que el dato desde un jtextfield, es 0

Tags: java, validación, jtextfield

Tengo un problema con un código en Java, Tengo dos JTextfield, los cuales utilizo para ingresar valores enteros y flotantes, enseguida tengo botones con la operaciones de: sumar, restar, dividir, multiplicar y residuo.

El problema radica en que, necesito impedir que cuando se presione el botón dividir se genere un Infinity, es decir, que no realice la operación ya que es un 0, ya sea 0 sobre algo o algo sobre 0.  Ya intente validar en el ActionPerformed:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if(!(txtNum1.getText().isEmpty() && txtNum2.getText().isEmpty())){ 
                if(!(txtNum1.getText().equals(0) && txtNum2.getText().equals(0))){ //En esta parte lo he intentado validar con el .equals
                    String val1 = txtNum1.getText();
                    String val2 = txtNum2.getText();
                    double n1 = Double.parseDouble(val1);
                    double n2 = Double.parseDouble(val2);
                    double n3 = n1/n2;
                    lblResultado.setText(String.valueOf(n3));
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Uno de los valores es cero corrigalo");
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("Uno de los dos campos esta vacio");
            }
        }
```

Pero sigue entrando en la operación, y no me arroga por consola la indicación que uno de los dos campos es 0.

El txtNum1 y txtNum2 esta declarados de la siguiente forma:

```
    txtNum1.setBounds(200, 50, 100, 50);
    txtNum1.setToolTipText("Nada distinto a Numeros!!!!");
    txtNum1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
            System.out.println("saludos desde el Pressed");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
            System.out.println("saludos desde el Released");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
            System.out.println("saludos desde el Typed");
            System.out.println("" + ke.getKeyChar()+"-->"+ke.getKeyCode());
            if(!(ke.getKeyChar() >= '0' && ke.getKeyChar() <= '9')&&!(ke.getKeyChar() == '.')){
                System.out.println("Caracter Invalido...");
                ke.consume();
            }
            if(ke.getKeyChar()=='.'&&txtNum1.getText().contains(".")){
                System.out.println("El caracter punto ya lo ingreso");
                ke.consume();
            }else{
                System.out.println("Caracter valido!!!");
            }
            //if(ke.getKeyChar() >= 48 && ke.getKeyChar() <= 57)
        }
        
    });
```

Aclaro, sumar 0, restar 0 esta permitido, pero el problema esta en la división.

Comment: Recuerda que solo el divisor no puede ser 0, el dividendo si puede serlo, por eso no deberías poner en tu condición el `&&`. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba cambiar el condicional a esto

```
if(Integer.parseInt(txtNum1.getText()) != 0 && Integer.parseInt(txtNum2.getText()) != 0){
```

La comparación que haces es de diferentes tipos.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el valor del EditText debes usar `.getText().toString()` y recuerda que este valor es un `String` por lo tanto debes comparar usando .equals() pero de esta forma

```
txtNum2.getText().toString().equals("0")
```

Este serìa el còdigo:

```
                if(!(txtNum1.getText().toString().equals("0") && txtNum2.getText().toString().equals("0"))){ 
                    String val1 = txtNum1.getText();
                    String val2 = txtNum2.getText();
                    double n1 = Double.parseDouble(val1);
                    double n2 = Double.parseDouble(val2);
                    double n3 = n1/n2;
                    lblResultado.setText(String.valueOf(n3));
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Uno de los valores es cero corrigalo");
                }
```